# How to change .exe name of Setup project VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

I would like to change setup.exe output name to myapp.exe.

I tried to change the .msi name by right click on setup project->select properties and then change output file name,

But how can I control on .exe file name also appeared on Release folder.

I tried follow according this question: [How to change the output name of an executable built by Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301058/how-to-change-the-output-name-of-an-executable-built-by-visual-studio)

But, there is not  "Application" tab of the properties window of setup project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

following screenshort will help you

[image]

Change name from there too

Comment: @Paramav Patel I tried to change the output file name also in Active(Release), Debug, Release and All configuration but it didn't help- only the .msi changed it's name but no the .exe file!

Comment: ok you want to change the name of .exe that display after installation ?

Comment: for example, you .msi name is "abc.msi" but after installation it shows exe as "def.exe" ?

Comment: ok then go to your project properties... in that go to application menu... in application menu you will find assembly information button.. click on it and change the information and save... now rebuild the project and all done

Comment: no not in setup project... in your actual application project... for which project you try to create a setup

Comment: I tried your solution which doesn't work! the details in Assembly information are different from the name of exe of my setup project.. and I created setup project for C# WPF project.

Answer (score 3):

Found some info.

When you select the Setup project in Solution Explorer, press **F4**.

You get the Deployment Project properties of the Setup project.

Here, you can change the name of the deployed program in **ProductName**, as it will appear in the user's Programs and Features. Here you can also change company name and the title of the setup dialog.