# I need to change the exe file name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

Change it by changing the assembly name. But in task manager (when program runs) it still shows the old name.How to correct it.I am using visual studio 2015.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the output name of an executable built by Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301058/how-to-change-the-output-name-of-an-executable-built-by-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating Title  in visual studio  Assembly information box

[image]