# Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\net5.0\SolutionName.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig exceeds the OS max path limit

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I was doing a project, I runned 1 time and it was fine, I runned the second time and this error appeard **"Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\net5.0\SolutionName.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig exceeds the OS max path limit. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characteres. SolutionName C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets   150".**

So I did a little research and the most common response was to re-install visual studio, so i did, but the error continued. So i create a new program and without doing any changes, in the new program, the same erros ocurred. The only thing i have in this new program is the main class with an "Hello world".

I assume its not a code problem and i can't find anything that answers why this error is appearing.

Comment: Try to move your project/solution to a folder with shorter path

Comment: What is the path of the project you're trying to compile? Is it a really long directory name?

Comment: @KlausGütter It worked, but why did the project only show this error after the first successful run?

Comment: @MartinCostello It is but the first time I runned it, it wasnt an issue.

Comment: But what is the path? You haven't actually given it, so we can't determine if it's more than 260 characters, which is the MAX_PATH limit on Windows.

Comment: @MartinCostello the path has more than 260, that part I understod. The parte that i dont understand is why I could run the program successful once before the error

Comment: My guess would be something a _rebuild_ does is hitting the MAX_PATH limit. If that's the case, the only fix is likely to be moving your project to a location on disk with a shorter path.

Comment: Map your long path to a drive letter, like X:, and use that.

Comment: I use such a mapping and it does not help, @DourHighArch. Visual Studio still reports about the long path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have also experienced a similar issue. I resolved it by moving my project to the root of my C: Drive to try and shorten the name and the path of the project.

Comment: i already fixed and that was it, the path to the project was to long, the only thing is that i dont know how could i run the program for like a week without any problems and in one day it wouldn work anymore.

Answer (score 15):

I have same error, and that is related with 'file name must be less than 260 characters'
and resolved by **Enabling Windows Long Path**
via reference link:
**https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/filr/filr-4/filr-desktop/t47bx2ogpfz7.html**

or do the following steps:

**1-** Click Window key and type gpedit.msc, then press the Enter key. This launches the Local Group Policy Editor.

**2-** Navigate to Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem.

**3-** Double click Enable NTFS long paths.

[image: like this image]

**4-** Select Enabled, then click OK.

**5-** at last restart visual studio

Comment: Caveat that this required a reboot for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced a similar issue. I resolved it by moving my project to the root of my C: Drive to try and shorten the name and the path of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You might solve this by editing the according registry entry:

- open registry editor
- navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
- open the 'LongPathsEnabled' property and set its value to 1
- restart visual studio